# Test color palette using selenium webdriver ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

How to test color **palette** using **selenium webdriver ruby**.I tried using the below code but it's not working

```
location=driver.find_element(:id,"color-palette").location
   driver.mouse.move_to(driver.find_element(:id,"color-palette"),location.x,location.y).click
```

Comment: What does your colour palette look like? Show the DOM please.

Comment: Could you please share also the `html` code here,for which you are using the `selenium-webdriver`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should do what you are trying to achieve. For further reference see [here](http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/b/bbc-selenium-webdriver-1.17.0/Selenium/WebDriver/ActionBuilder.html#method-i-click)

```
el = driver.find_element(:id, "color-palette")
driver.action.click(el).perform
```

Or try changing your code from

```
driver.mouse.move_to(driver.find_element(:id,"color-palette"),location.x,location.y).click
```

to

```
driver.action.move_to(driver.find_element(:id,"color-palette"),location.x,location.y).click
```

Comment: Could you give me the link of `mouse` method?

Comment: @RubyLovely : Check the documentation at http://www.ruby-doc.org/gems/docs/b/bbc-selenium-webdriver-1.17.0/Selenium/WebDriver/Mouse.html